# Compiler Optimizations

Tags: c, optimization, compiler-optimization

The optimizer at levels −o2 and −o3 transforms the loop in
Example 2−30(a) to something like the code in Example 2−30(b).

[image]

I don't understand why compiler made a optimization like that ? Is there any difference between downcounting and upcounting ?

Comment: On ```gcc``` try to use ```-S``` flag to see the ```dis-assembled``` code. Then try to see what is the difference between optimized and non-optimized code.

Comment: Which compiler?

Comment: Thinking logically, if you compare `i` to zero you do not need to keep the value N around in a register or memory location.

Comment: Is this a real example or an academic one? Which exercise 2-30?

Comment: This example is an optimization of Texas Instruments' C6000 compiler. Actually, I came across it in a document by Texas Instruments.

Comment: This looks like a very artificial example because there is no loop body which would affect whether or not the compiler is permitted to perform such an optimization

Comment: This is a FAQ. For many instruction sets, compares vs zero are ever so slightly less expensive than compares against a value.

Comment: Some compilers do some not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Most CPUs have internal arithmetic flags which hold the data on the last arithmetic operation.
One of such flags is "zero flag" which is set when the result is zero.
So when the loop counter is decremented from `N` to 0, once 0 is reached, it is enough to perform a single operation which just checks for the zero flag in order to know if the loop exit condition is reached.

When the loop counter is incremented from 0 to `N`, each iteration you need to perform comparison between the current loop counter and `N` (which is basically a subtract operation in most cases) and then check the zero flag (to catch the case when the loop counter is equal to `N`).

Thus in case (b) you perform one operation less compared to case (a).

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful comment. If you suggest any documents on this subject, I would be happy to read and learn.

Comment: @Paroz This is very much dependent on the CPU architecture for which the compiler optimizes the code. You can just google for some C "tips and tricks", performing for loops which count down to 0 is preferable in most cases (as well as `while` loops).
I don't know if there is a good book which summarizes everything that exists today.

Answer (score 0):

Some compiler do, some do not optimize this way:

```
void foo(int N)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) x();
}
```

GCC does not

```
foo:
        test    edi, edi
        jle     .L6
        push    rbp
        mov     ebp, edi
        push    rbx
        xor     ebx, ebx
        sub     rsp, 8
.L3:
        xor     eax, eax
        add     ebx, 1
        call    x
        cmp     ebp, ebx
        jne     .L3
        add     rsp, 8
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        ret
.L6:
        ret
```

CLANG does

```
foo:                                    # @foo
        test    edi, edi
        jle     .LBB0_4
        push    rbx
        mov     ebx, edi
.LBB0_2:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        xor     eax, eax
        call    x@PLT
        dec     ebx
        jne     .LBB0_2
        pop     rbx
.LBB0_4:
        ret
```

I would like to see a real performance comparison

Comment: On x86 the difference is probably not mentionable, it uses `jne` in either case. On other ISA (like the whole classic Motorola side of things) where you have a "branch if zero" instruction, the difference is immediately noticed since that's a faster instruction than "branch if equal" which would take parameters as input rather than peek at the condition code register.